# Nginx Redirect Url containing "PHP"

Tags: redirect, nginx

Recently I changed my website that was used PHP/Apache to Django/Nginx. I would like to give a http response 301 and redirect to my main page all requests that contain ".php" in url.

Example:

```
example.com/**?page=show.php&id=2748**

example.com/**index.php?page=show_page.php&id=2748**
```

The ".php" can be in any position in the URL.

I tried:

```
location ~ \.php {
        rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.example.com permanent;
    }
```

But, of course, it just work when have .php in the end. Can anybody give me a clue?

UPDATED:
If I use this solution:

```
            if ($request_uri ~* "php") {
           rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.example.com permanent;
        }
```

I get the following error in the log:

```
[29/Aug/2011:13:30:25 -0300] "GET /?page=show_page.php&id=2748 HTTP/1.0" 301 184 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0"
[29/Aug/2011:13:30:26 -0300] "GET /?page=show_page.php&id=2748 HTTP/1.0" 301 184 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0"
[29/Aug/2011:13:30:26 -0300] "GET /?page=show_page.php&id=2748 HTTP/1.0" 301 184 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0"
[29/Aug/2011:13:30:27 -0300] "GET /?page=show_page.php&id=2748 HTTP/1.0" 301 184 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0"
[29/Aug/2011:13:30:27 -0300] "GET /?page=show_page.php&id=2748 HTTP/1.0" 301 184 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0"
[29/Aug/2011:13:30:28 -0300] "GET /?page=show_page.php&id=2748 HTTP/1.0" 301 184 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0"
[29/Aug/2011:13:30:28 -0300] "GET /?page=show_page.php&id=2748 HTTP/1.0" 301 184 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0"
```

Why it tries to redirect too many times?

UPDATED:

I Tried:

```
  if ($request_uri ~ .*.php.*) {
        rewrite ^/ http://www.example.com permanent;
    }
```

its working, but when the URL starts with "?" I get same error. So, 50% of the problem was solved...

SOLUTION:

```
        if ($request_uri ~ .*.php.*) {
            #return 410;
        rewrite ^ http://$host? permanent;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was in the rewrite.

I changed rewrite to return code 410, I think that I would do that instead return return 301 (permanent).

So, here is the code:

```
if ($request_uri ~ .*.php.*) {
        return 410;
}
```

Now, nginx will return 4010 for all pages that that contain ".php" in anywhere in URL. My django site can live in peace now ;-)

Comment: Well, after some days I realized that I really needed permanent redirect. Here is the correct solution:        if ($request_uri ~ .*.php.*) {
            #return 410;
        rewrite ^ http://$host? permanent;

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

Add the following along with your existing condition:

```
if ($args ~* "php") {
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.site.com permanent;
}
```

Comment: Hello RakeshS, it doesnt work... If I check the log I will get: 

[29/Aug/2011:13:30:25 -0300] "GET /?page=show_page.php&id=2748 HTTP/1.0" 301 184 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0"
[29/Aug/2011:13:30:26 -0300] "GET /?page=show_page.php&id=2748 HTTP/1.0" 301 184 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0"
[29/Aug/2011:13:30:26 -0300] "GET /?page=show_page.php&id=2748 HTTP/1.0" 301 184 "-" 

(the same message are repeated for a couple of times and a error show in my browser)

Comment: @Thomas-bryan I have posted the updated settings, please give it a try.

Comment: the same problem happened. I tried put a "break" but it doesnt work as well....