# How check in nginx for query_string parameters?

Tags: nginx, web-server, configuration, rewrite, url

How I can write a condition in the nginx config testing if a `q` parameter was entered in the URL?

This doesn't work:

```
 if ($arg_q) {
   return 301 "/someurl";
 }
```

It catches URLs like

```
/search?entered_search=1&q=123
```

But it doesn't catch URLs like

```
/search?entered_search=1&q=
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this might work. It says "if the query string contains the sequence 'q=' send a redirect". At least that's what I think it says, I'm not great with regex. I've tested it and it works, but there may be side effects depending what query strings you could get.

```
if ($query_string ~ q=) {
  return 301 "https://www.example.com";
}
```

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/310124/nginx-redirect-url-containing-php) helped me work it out.